# How to recover space after Visual Studio 2013 updates?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Before installing VS 2013 I expanded my VM volume to have 20GB free space.
After installing VS 2013 only 8GB was left. Visual Studio 2013 update 3 took another 6GB of my hard drive. I haven't even installed C++ and WinPhone SDK..

I've tried to find what does take so much space.

- Disk Cleanup shows nothing to recover.
- Temp is 1GB not related to VS.
- VS 12.0 folder in program files is 2.3GB (not much changed after update in here).
- No shadow copies configured

My OS Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: what version of VS2013 did you install and if it isn't the Express Edition, could you sacrifice IDE features for free disk space? Going with the "lowest" possible edition still gives you msbuild and a debugger, depending on what you would actually need on the server.

Comment: I don't want to sacrifice features and the feature I don't want to sacrifice the most is plugin support. I just cant comprehend why so much space is required?! I know there are tools like Blend and SQL server but still... almost double the size after update?

Comment: remove Blend and Lightswitch, for example, if you're not using those.

Comment: I'm using both of them, once again - my concern is not a raising size or even size of the package. The problem is - every time I update it inflates by almost 2 no matter what are features installed.

Comment: Microsoft writes installers that allow an update to be uninstalled, rolling back to the unpatched version.  Nice, keeps plenty of programmers out of trouble.  The space needed for the files that were replaced, lots and lots of them, is of course not for free.  You'll need to ask at superuser.com how that space can be recovered.  Surely already asked, make sure you search for it first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right, updating Visual Studio will eat disk space , It is a problem If like me have an small SSD hard disk.

No matter where your Visual Studio is installed , it eat disk space on Windows drive.
The files occupying space in the following path:

C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\

There is discussions about whether delete this folder or not on the web.

There are other things (except above folder) that take disk spaces, you can run *Disk cleaner softwares* and be sure to select things like (they may not selected by default):

- Windows update
- Software Temporary Installation

Comment: Windows Update Cleanup (available under the "admin" version of the cleanup tools) combine packages that target the same product and can reclaim quite a bit of space.

Comment: The biggest problem I found is, every update adds a lot and sometimes it looks like Visual Studio size is being doubled or tripled after time (i.e. try installing VS 2013 and apply all subsequent updates). If you install VS 2013 and update straight to Update 4 it will be way smaller than VS 2013 > Upd 2 > Upd 3 > Upd 4.

Answer (score 0):

I have an 80 Gb SSD and a larger HDD. The VS install was using too much space on the SSD, what I did was copy some of it's folders to my HDD, delete the original folders, then link them back to their original paths as directory junctions. Haven't noticed any problems with this arrangement so far.

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs` points to `D:\ssd\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits` points to `D:\ssd\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits`
- `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` points to `D:\ssd\ProgramData\Package Cache`

Saved around 6 Gb on my SSD.
P.S. When I read about what package cache is, I thought it's one of most ridiculous Microsoft ideas ever.